# how to set color of label in chartjs?

Tags: chart.js

I created a chart with chartJS and I would like to change the color of data label and date. What's wrong?

```js
const labels = <?php echo json_encode($Date) ?>;

const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Données Vent',
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        data: <?php echo json_encode($Vent) ?>,
        data: <?php echo json_encode($Rafale) ?>,
    }]
};

const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        color: 'white', //couleur du titre graphique
        scales: {
            y: {
                color:"white",
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    },
};

const myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), config);
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, the normal way is : `options >  legend > labels > fontColor (or color)`

Comment: hello thanks for your help  .i think you're allright but i don't know where i have to put my script. it seems that i have to put" color" now. i tried in different. place but it' doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

changed label color like follows:

```
 options: { 
            legend: {
                labels: {
                    fontColor: "blue",
                    fontSize: 18
                }
            },
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Robin Hood @pistou

finally it's now different. i do like this:

```
        hAxis: { direction: -1,
                 textStyle: {
                    color:'white',
                 }},
        vAxis: { 
                 textStyle: {
                    color:'white',
                 }},
```